# How print pdf with default printer in java?

Tags: java, file, pdf, printing, default

After a long search , I could not find a way to print a file ( pdf ) with my printer.

I wish that I would open the dialog box where you set the pages and copies .

The desktop class print file immediately and I do not want this .
Thank's for your help!

Comment: You want to read a pdf and print the content on the console? Or send it to the printer machine?

Comment: Everything you need is in the [javax.print](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/print/package-summary.html) package, including the print settings dialog.

Comment: Hi, i want to send my pdf to the printer machine..

Comment: I know that there's job printer class with opendialog method but it don't read my file..

Comment: @MassimilianoSmillovich does that mean you have tried to print the PDF with the APIs in [javax.print](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/print/package-summary.html)?

If those APIs did not work for you, you may have a printer that does not directly support printing a PDF. You can instead take a look at [iText](http://itextpdf.com), [PDFBox](https://pdfbox.apache.org), or [Datalogics](https://github.com/datalogics/pdf-java-toolkit-samples) solutions.

Comment: I tried but it didn't works.
If I open the dialog with "opendialog" method, it doesn't keep my pdf!
Can someone post working code please?